# Responsive DIV scaling within "background-size: contain" image

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, positioning

***UPDATED 01/01/15***

### Problem:

I have a centered background image that is scaling with `background-size: contain`. I would like to have DIVs (for links, etc.) that overlay on the background and also scale with said background whenever the browser is resized, but also stay positioned relative to that background's size.

In the Fiddle provided below, the red border shows where the navbar should exist and the green border shows where the 'Home' button should be. Resize your browser window as far as you can both horizontally, then vertically -- you should see how the bars do not stay positioned properly over the image at certain extremes.

**Update/Progress:** I have it scaling appropriately in all scenarios *except* when the browser is resized to a narrow vertical window. Then the navbar and home DIVs shift downward and don't stay positioned relative to the image.

### Fiddle:

Original Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tc4hoLft/

**New Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w5xjkj4e/1/**

### Code:

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    background: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.bg {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/350/325');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 14%;
    top: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#home {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 21.5%;
    width: 7%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {

    var width = $('.bg').width();
    var height = $('.bg').height();

    var imgWidth = width > height ? 350/325 * height : width;
    var imgHeight = height > width ? 325/350 * width : height;
    var imgTop;

    $('.navbar').css({
        'width': imgWidth,
        'height': imgHeight * .15,
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm actually somewhat close, I think. The only problem I am still having is when I make the browser window very narrow vertically, the DIVs shift down and don't stay positioned properly.

Updated Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w5xjkj4e/1/).

I'm resorting to JavaScript to get the actual background image size, then calculating the DIV's size and position based on those results.

```
$(window).on("resize", function() {

    var width = $('.bg').width();
    var height = $('.bg').height();

    var imgWidth = width > height ? 350/325 * height : width;
    var imgHeight = height > width ? 325/350 * width : height;
    var imgTop; //need to do calculations on this

    $('.navbar').css({
        'width': imgWidth,
        'height': imgHeight * .15,
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use background-size: contain, if you can use `background-size: cover` (without the image degrading too much), then the background image will fill the container completely. Since the percentage positions are relative to the container, they are now also relative to the image. So they now stay much closer to their original positions over the image.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but ``cover`` is unusable with the image dimensions and suffers from the exact same issue as ``contain`` with extreme resizes. Besides, when it comes to a navigation bar, you can't just have things "close"... you need pixel precision, otherwise buttons don't link to the appropriate things! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tc4hoLft/2/)**

By the use `background-size: cover;` you can achieve that.

```
html, body {
    background: url("https://placekitten.com/350/325") no-repeat scroll center center / cover #000;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 325px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check this out. **[Perfect Full Page Background Image](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)**

Another solution can be `background-size: 100% 100%;`

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tc4hoLft/3/)**

Comment: Again, ``cover`` and ``contain` have very different functionality. This is not even remotely close to what I asked and is simply a repeat of the above two answers. Additionally, it doesn't even work, because if you resize the browser, the DIVs do not scale appropriately at all with the image.

Comment: Did you tried `background-size: 100% 100%;` with `contain`? I did checked cover functionality while resizing in the browser it was working fine in firefox for me. What browser you are using ?

Comment: Yes, I tried those. Apply your settings to my Fiddle. The differences are obvious. I don't want a full screen, covered background image. I want a contained image scaled appropriately with the ability to overlay DIVs and have them stay in position relative to the scaled contained background.

Comment: Can you please add snapshot of the issue in the question with the details. I am not clear what actually you want. Thanks

Comment: I want overlay DIVs to stay positioned relative to the size of the background image using ``contain``. Only using ``contain``. Not ``cover``. Not ``100%``. Only ``contain``.